# How to show label/text on Here Maps Polygon object

Tags: here-api

Here Maps official documentation for Polygon does not contain any reference about how to add a label for the polygon.

[image]

Polygon Documentation - https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-polygon.html

Here Maps Polygon Example - https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/geoshapes/polygon-on-the-map

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a straight-forward way, but with a few lines of code you can create a custom svg "icon" that contains only your text, and display it anywhere on the map:

```
var my_text = 'My text';
var svg = '<svg  width="80" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="0" y="20" font-size="10pt" font-family="Arial">' + my_text + '</text></svg>';
var icon = new H.map.Icon(svg);
var marker = new H.map.Marker({lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }, {icon: icon});
map.addObject(marker);
```

This displays 'My text' over Berlin. You find more documentation at this [example from the HERE documentation](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/markers/map-with-svg-graphic-markers).